# Unable to use Logitech C270 in Fedora 25 under VirtualBox

Tags: fedora, drivers, virtualbox, virtual-machine, camera

I have a Fedora 25 VM running on VirtualBox 5.1.14 under Windows 10, and a USB webcam (Logitech C270) plugged in.

I have configured the USB filter properly so far as I can tell:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to show up:

```
[craig@localhost ~]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
[craig@localhost ~]$
```

Even after manually loading `uvcvideo`:

```
[craig@localhost ~]$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo
[craig@localhost ~]$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
vboxvideo              49152  2
vboxguest             266240  7 vboxsf,vboxvideo
ttm                    94208  1 vboxvideo
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 vboxvideo
drm                   339968  5 vboxvideo,ttm,drm_kms_helper
video                  40960  0
[craig@localhost ~]$
```

The output of `lsusb` is the same. If I open **Cheese**, there's no video device:

[image]

All the resources I found suggest this should "just work", but I'm having issues. Where should I look next?